# ADO EF Code First Generic Intermediate Class Inheritance mapping

Tags: entity-framework, generics, inheritance, mapping, entity-framework-4.1

I've got the following requirement that works well in the OO space but I can't seem to get it to map back to the DB using ADO EF code first.

I have numrous products each will have different aspects (attributes but not in the sense of code attributes). For instance ring would have aspects such as mineral type = gold etc whilst a diamond would have an aspec of clarity = VVSI1.

As you can see the products very greatly in thier composition and I want a dynamic way of growing my system.

As such I've created a product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private List<ProductAspect> aspects = new List<ProductAspect>();
    public List<ProductAspect> Aspects { get { return aspects; } set { aspects = value; } }
}
```

It has a list of ProductAspect which is the base class for all aspects moving forward:

```
public class ProductAspect 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string AspectName { get; set; }
}
```

I then inherit from the ProductAspect using a generic which alows me to be specific (strongly typed) about my Aspect Value:

```
public abstract class ProductAspect<T> : ProductAspect
{
    public T AspectValue { get; set; }
}
```

I then create some Aspects that will allow me to decorate my product:

```
public class StringAspect : ProductAspect<string> { };
public class DecimalAspect : ProductAspect<decimal> { };
public class ImageAspect : ProductAspect<byte[]> { };
```

I then give the DbContext a try and have tried both TPH and TPC inheritance mappings.

Neither seem to work. The DB model that get's generated doesn't create a foriegn key to the StringAspect or DecimalAspect tables from the Aspect Table.

```
public class IxamDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductAspect> Aspects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        AspectMapping(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void AspectMapping(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
        //TPH
        //mb.Entity<ProductAspect>()
        //    .Map<StringAspect>(m => m.Requires("type").HasValue("sa"))
        //    .Map<DecimalAspect>(m => m.Requires("type").HasValue("da"));

        //TPC
        //mb.Entity<StringAspect>().ToTable("StringAspect");
        //mb.Entity<DecimalAspect>().ToTable("DecimalAspect");
    }
}
```

Resulting in the following exception for this Seeding code:

```
        Product p = new Product();
        p.Name = "Diamond";
        p.Aspects.Add(new StringAspect() { AspectName = "History", AspectValue = "Old and long" });
        p.Aspects.Add(new DecimalAspect() { AspectName = "Weight", AspectValue= 96.5M });


        context.Products.Add(p);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Excpetion:

> EntityType 'StringAspect' does not
>   exist in the EntitySet
>   'IxamDataContext.Aspects'. Parameter
>   name: entity

Any ideas from the EF code first pros out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't support intermediate non mapped types in inheritance hierarchy. It means that you can't have this inheritance: A (mapped) -> B (not mapped) -> C (mapped). EF also doesn't support mapping generic types. It means that you must remove your generic intermediate class from the hierarchy and move `AspectValue` to derived types with correct type.

Comment: By chance, do you know if EF Core 2.0 does support this ? (could be a nice time to migrate...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's to late, but I would offer you using [ComplexType attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx) it will allows you to extend your types as you wish.