# Controlling TPT-mapping of properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to control how Entity Framework 6 maps my class hierarchy into tables so that the properties in an abstract class in the middle of my hierarchy is mapped to the descendant types, not to its base class.

My class hierarchy is quite simple:

```
public abstract class BaseType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateField { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DerivedAbstract : BaseType
{
    public string MapToChild { get; set; }
}

public class Concrete1 : DerivedAbstract
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Concrete2 : DerivedAbstract
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have setup a simple table-per-type hierarchy:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseType>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Concrete1>().ToTable("Concrete1");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Concrete2>().ToTable("Concrete2");
}
```

And this gives me three tables: `BaseTypes`, `Concrete1` and `Concrete2`. So far I am very happy, but my challenge is that the field `MapToChild` defined in the `DerivedAbstract` class is mapped down to the `BaseTypes` table instead of to both of the `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` tables.

This makes sense in most cases, but not in the project I am working on. So I am looking for a way to tell Entity Framework that I want the property to be mapped to the two tables `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` instead.

So far I have been unable to find a way to do this. Does Entity Framework even support it?

Comment: what happens if you add a class : `public class Concrete3 : BaseType { public string prop {get; set;}}`  with `modelBuilder.Entity<Concrete3>().ToTable("Concrete3");`.

Comment: Getting the same situation. MapToChild is still in the BaseTypes table

Comment: Are you needing to do polymorphic queries?

Comment: This so answer implies this isn't supported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776635/ado-ef-code-first-generic-intermediate-class-inheritance-mapping

Comment: You are probably right. I will leave the question open for a few days to see if there is an answer, but if not then feel free to post an answer saying that this is not supported and I will accept it.

Comment: No, this isn't supported. In fact you want a mixture of TPT, where all common properties are in the base table, and TPC, where all types have their own tables (they "inherit" the properties from the base type). Ideally, you'd want to choose which properties inherit and which don't. There is no API for that, although technically, in DBMS terms, this wouldn't be a problem. But are you sure you want a base table for *each* type? TPT can have heavy performance impact because everything requires joins or dual inserts.

Comment: I would like a table for each type so that I can easily separate shared data and the specifics for each type. Performance is not too important for we are working with a rather limited amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are telling it to map BaseType. So it is creating base type as a TPH mapping and adding a discriminator.

If you remove the BaseType mapping you will get a Table for concrete1 and a table for concrete2 which I think it was you want. Right?

Ah... sorry, probably what you want. I can't map your classes so that BaseType is a table and have the MapToChild be in each concrete type. I assume you are doing this so you can query BaseType and get back multiple child types.

So, never mind.

Comment: No, I actually want the base class in a separate table. What I don't want is for all other abstract classes to be mapped to that table as well. I want their data in the tables for the concrete classes.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, and corrected to never mind. You'll need someone that knows more about it than I to do this mapping, it is is possible. Of course, dropping the intermediate class would work, it's not the best answer.